# How to access text from UITextField Swift 2

Tags: swift, uitextfield, xcode7

I have Swift 2 and I can't access my textfield's text, what should I do?

```
@IBOutlet weak var CoolField: UITextField!
let texts = Int(CoolField.text?)
```

There is always the error message that Instance member CoolField cannot be used with type ViewController

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32884023/default-parameter-values-error-instance-member-cannot-be-used-on-type-viewcont) relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot define the following as class variable `let texts = Int(CoolField.text?)` , it doesn't work like that in Swift :

Keep this defined as it is : `@IBOutlet weak var CoolField: UITextField!`

Define under it as class variable :  `var texts : Int!`

Then use it in `viewDidLoad` for example like :   `texts = Int(CoolField.text!)`

Thats should work fine, Good luck !