# Having trouble with NSCalendar and NSDate in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift2, nscalendar

I'm having difficulties to get the right now command with the Swift 2.0, my command lists are below:

```
let dateNow = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let hour = calendar.component(NSCalendarUnit.Hour, fromDate: dateNow)
let minute = calendar.component(NSCalendarUnit.Minute, fromDate: dateNow)
```

The error said that instances calendar cannot be used in ViewController, and what confuses me is that the line above (the let calendar = ...) clearly defines calendar as a constant but why cannot I access it for my let hour and minute? please help

Comment: I've test your code, it was compiled successfully

Comment: You can try to Clean your project, and DerivedData folder

Comment: I tried to clean it already and it still gives me the same error, what do you mean by DerivedData folder?

Comment: close Xcode, remove all subfolders from "/Users/%USER%/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData", and empty the thrash. It's folder with Xcode projects cache and indexes

Comment: This may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32884023/default-parameter-values-error-instance-member-cannot-be-used-on-type-viewcont

Comment: solved it already! I have to define each of them inside a function rather than in my own class. Thank you for your responses.